# prove that $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}\ge\sqrt{\frac{32(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{ab+bc+ac}-23}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c>0$ prove or disprove
$$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a}\ge\sqrt{\dfrac{32(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{ab+bc+ac}-23}$$I don't know how to begin to solve this problem

Comment: Did you consider ways to remove the square root?

Comment: then It's ugly.

Comment: Ugly, expanded, lots of simple terms...  it depends on how you look at it I guess...

Comment: when I deal other problem guess it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try $$a=1,b=2,c=3$$ and you see this is not true.